# Reviewer declined flag on own post

Tags: discussion, review

I just had a flag declined by the person whose answer I flagged. Then another moderator came along and flagged it for the same reason I did; it was a link-only answer. So I lost a point even though my flag was correct.

Should the person whose content is flagged be allowed to review that flag themselves?

The question is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190488/what-is-securitydescriptor-format/191123). The answer by Wictor Wilen is the one I flagged and Waqas Sarwar commented the same as I did. Now my comment that he should bring parts of the link into the answer is missing.

Comment: happened with me also, due to that, I was blocked from raising flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I declined that flag (not the author), based on the fact that the answer was indeed answering the question. With out without the link / new update it is clearly intended to answer the question.

Therefore the flag "not an answer" had no merit according to me.

The "low quality" flag would have been a better choice, but if you ask me the answer was of a good enough quality even before the edit. Sure it did not include details from the mentioned link but it did answer the question independently from the link.

As always, this is a human process where there is no one truth but the above is my explanation to the specific events.

Also to clarify:

- I handled the flag, but did not write the answer = no bias in that sort
- You have not written any comment on this answer, so no comment of yours has been deleted

Comment: I think his post answered the question from the title of the question, but not the OP's questions about syntax or how to crawl external data from OData service. I understand your point about NAA versus VLQ, and this is good learning opportunity for me, since there's not authoritative guidance available for new reviewers. I would also swear that when I click the link to review my flag that had been declined, that it showed me who declined it and that it was Wictor, but obviously I can't check that now. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

That answer was only reviewed by one person, not the author: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/66430

The review then ended early because the flag was declined. The flag was declined by a moderator though, not the author.

The author of the post *did* edit, possibly in response to the review comment, but this wasn't done *from* review.

Comment: The author is a moderator. He declined my flag. Another moderator came by later and acted on it the same way I did. The author made changes after declining my flag.

Comment: @erinl I was the reviewer, but I'm not the author of the post. I have chipped in my reasoning in my own answer below.

Comment: I did not decline your flag! I did however update the post with more details to satisfy everyones need, even though I actually answered the post. Nevertheless - this IS a big issue with SE, you copy/paste from the authorative page and then if the authoriative page is fixed/updated SE isn't -> which makes SE incorrect. Also in this specific example, you cannot elaborate on the answer in a good way except having an article as big as the one I linked to.